# Probability to all bacteria being descendants of one after N steps

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I believe this is a well known problem, but I was unable to find the solution myself.

In a vessel there is a 1 million bacteria. Every hour every bacteria produces two new bacteria and dies itself (i.e. the amount of the bacteria doubles).

Straight after this one half of all the bacteria is killed by random using a uniform distribution (I am not sure it is really a uniform distribution, but the algorithm is as follows: mixing them very well, them passing over all pairs of bacteria and throwing a coin which one will be killed). In an hour everything is repeated on and on.

What is the probability that after 1000 hours all of the bacteria in the vessel are descendants of just one bacteria (i.e. who lived 1000 hours ago ago) - but not a specific one, i.e. they all may be descendants of bacteria #1 or bacteria #2, or ... or bacteria #1,000,000?

Comment: This process is not well-defined unless you say how the pairs are formed. However, it seems to me that the pairs are just an artefact that's not important to what you're trying to do, and you could simply say that a subset of one million of the two million bacteria is chosen uniformly at random from all subsets of that size?

Comment: Yes, you are right. We have 2 million bacteria and we have N ways to choose 1 million out of them. So every of these way has equal probability.

Comment: For a simple case with just two bacteria A and B we have after 1 hour: A1, A2, B1, B2 and then after half killed 6 variants: A1A2, B1B2, A1B1, A1B2, A2B1, A2B2. Probability that both bacteria descendants remain is 4/6 = 2/3. So after 2 hours the probability that descendants of both A and B are remaining is 2/3 * 2/3. After N hours it is (2/3)^N and consequently the probability that after N steps there remain descendants of only one original bacteria is 1 - (2/3)^N. This number fast approaches 1 with growing N.